# Having some trouble understanding Facades and Service Providers

Tags: php, laravel

I've been reading the documentation up and down now, still not sure what I'm doing wrong. In my opinion the documentation is very difficult to understand for a beginner.

Anyway, I'm trying to make something akin to the `Auth::user()` method, where it returns additional data about a logged in user that I will be needing for this application.

I have this helper class here:

```
namespace App\Helpers;

use Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Models\Grouping\User;
use App\Models\Grouping\Client;
use App\Models\Grouping\Rank;

class ClientUser {
    public function __construct($request) {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function client() {
        return Client::find($this->request->session()->get('client_id'));
    }

    public function auth() {
        if (Auth::check()) {
            // Get the client
            $client = $this->client();

            // Get the client's user
            $user = $client->users()->find(Auth::user()['id']);

            // Get the rank of the logged in user
            $rank = Rank::find($user->pivot->rank_id);

            return [
                'user' => $user,
                'rank' => $rank,
                'client' => $client
            ];
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

This is responsible for doing what I described, returning additional data that I can't get through `Auth::user()`. Now I'm trying to register this class in the `AuthServiceProvider`

```
public function register()
    {
      // Register client auth
      $request = $this->app->request;

      $this->app->singleton(ClientUser::class, function ($app) {
        return new ClientUser($request);
      });
    }
```

Now what I don't understand is how I'm supposed to make this globally accessible throughout my app like `Auth::user()` is.

The problem with just making "importing" it is that it needs the request object, which is why I'm passing it through the service container.

Now here's where I'm stuck. I'm not able to access `app` in my controller or anywhere, and I can't define a Facade because a Facade expects you to return a string of the bound service that it should "alias?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your service provider like this :

```
$this->app->bind('client.user', function ($app) {
        return new ClientUser($app->request);
      });
```

Create another class extended from `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade`.

```
namespace App\Facades;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

class ClientUserFacade extends Facade {
    public static function getFacadeAccessor(){
         return "client.user";
    }
}
```

Add `'ClientUser => ClientUserFacade::class` in `alias` key of `app.php`

Comment: This still doesn't resolve my confusion, how do I make a facade out of this so I can do `ClientUser::user()`?